# Match url with the pattern

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am opening a filters.txt file. Below is the file:

```
http://www.somehost.com/.*/releases, RE,TO
```

I am comparing the first entry in the text file with the hard coded url in my code. Any URL that starts with the pattern(firstentry) in the text file should do this in particular if loop. Here this url `http://www.somehost.com/news/releases/2011/09/07/somehost-and-life-care-networks-launch-3g-mobile-health-project-help-patien` is originated from this pattern url only `http://www.somehost.com/.*/releases`. But still it is not matching this pattern. Any suggestions why is it happening?

```
BufferedReader readbuffer = null;
            try {
                readbuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filters.txt"));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String strRead;



        try {
            while ((strRead=readbuffer.readLine())!=null){
                String splitarray[] = strRead.split(",");
                String firstentry = splitarray[0];
                String secondentry = splitarray[1];
                String thirdentry = splitarray[2];



                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^" +firstentry);
                Matcher m = p.matcher("http://www.somehost.com/news/releases/2011/09/07/somehost-and-life-care-networks-launch-3g-mobile-health-project-help-patien");

                if (m.find() && thirdentry.startsWith("LO")) {
                  //Do whatever

                    System.out.println("First Loop");

                }

                else if(m.find() && thirdentry.startsWith("TO"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Second Loop");
                }

                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you please clearly provide your regex and samples of the URLS that need matching?

Comment: @Benjamin.. I have provided the text file above... That text file has one entry as mentioned above... I am testing on that url first of all.. Any url which start with the pattern in the text file url should do whatever in that if loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try seperating the `find()` and your if/else. You need to call the `find()` only once in your for loop.

[Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) says:
  `Matcher.find() Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.` Next is quite important, it means it skips to the next possible match every time you call the method.

```
boolean found = m.find();
if (found && thirdentry.startsWith("LO")) {
//Do whatever
  System.out.println("First Loop");
}
else if(found && thirdentry.startsWith("TO"))
{
  System.out.println("Second Loop");
}
```